# Is this sentence missing a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas

This is a sentence from a passage in a reading comprehension problem solving book.

> The historians excelled in the elaborateness of understandings they developed in their ability to pose alternative explanations for events and in their use of additional evidence.

At first, this sentence didn't seem to be making any sense. "...understandings they developed in their ability to ..."? Then I realized it would make perfect sense if there were a comma between "developed" and "in".

> The historians excelled in the elaborateness of understandings they developed, in their ability to pose alternative explanations for events and in their use of additional evidence.

However, the sentence is written without any commas in the original text (https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=QZb7PnTgSCgC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=the+historians+excelled+in+the+elaborateness+of+understandings+they+developed&source=bl&ots=FtHTlKis_I&sig=WjUmK-keCIhAqu2XdAevW44qu8s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi699HCq83WAhUGE5QKHQUdBXsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=the%20historians%20excelled%20in%20the%20elaborateness%20of%20understandings%20they%20developed&f=false) as well. Is there any way to understand the sentence as it is, without adding or omitting anything?

Comment: Since there seem to be no other examples of "excelled in the elaborateness" on the net, never mind  "excelled in the elaborateness of understandings", I'd class the whole lot as worthy of replacement (the original and the book giving this example). But the comma would seem to make a minor improvement.

Comment: My thoughts entirely, the literary equivalent of someone who likes the sound of their own voice. "The historians excelled at using all the evidence available to construct alternative explanations."

Comment: Can someone tell me why this question was downvoted? I'm new here, so there's a lot that I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: it needs that comma (and preferably a second, serial comma).

The historians excelled in three things: "in the elaborateness of understandings they developed, in their ability to pose alternative explanations for events, and in their use of additional evidence."

Its meaning remains, perhaps, somewhat elusive.